# Laravel mail sending to self

Tags: laravel, email, notifications

I've got a contact form that requires a persons Name, Email, Subject and Message in order to send an email. The email successfully sends however the "to" and "from" are from the same email. Here's the controller code:

```
Mail::send('email-contact',[ 
            'msg' => $request->message
        ], function ($mail) use ($request) {
            $mail->from($request->email, $request->name);
            $mail->to('testcontactacc1@gmail.com')->subject($request->subject);
        });
```

In this case the email sends properly but the "from" field is the same name.

For example I get:

To: "testcontactacc1@gmail.com", From: "testcontactacc1@gmail.com".

Instead of:

To: "testcontactacc1@gmail.com", From: "{the user's email from $request->email}".

What am I doing wrong?

In my .env I have:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=testcontactacc1@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=**********
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Comment: You are using Gmail account for the different identity of the sender you should use your own cpanel SMTP server. Gmail does not provide custom identity.

Comment: Oh thanks for that. I changed it to my own cpanel SMTP and it works perfectly

Comment: I am updating this to answer can you please mark as an answer then this question will be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Gmail account for the different identity of the sender you should use your own cpanel SMTP server. Gmail does not provide custom identity.